# Allow user and program to use a directory (read/write) outside /home

Tags: permissions, directory

There is currently an issue with [Mendeley](http://support.mendeley.com/customer/portal/questions/332632-mendeley-desktop-fails-to-open-download-pdf) in Ubuntu and ecryptfs home folders

The only workaround at this time is to allow Mendeley to write/read to another folder outside the ecrypted `/home` folder.

How can I make a folder under `/` readable and writable to the program and user in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a folder using sudo and then change the owner to your user.  From the command-line:

```
cd /
sudo mkdir mendeley
sudo chown myuser:myuser mendeley
```

Replace `myuser` with whatever your username is.  That should create the folder `/mendeley` which is owned by your current user which you can use, any subdirectories or files in that directory will be owned by that user but should remain unencrypted.  Maybe a better folder name would be `unencrypted` and add a `/unencrypted/mendeley` subdirectory in there.